# Simulate multiple mouse clicks or touch input at the same time using Python

Tags: python, mouseevent, touch-event, pynput

I have been using `pynput` package in Python to simulate mouse clicks. I have a keyboard listener and when 'x' is pressed, mouse pointer will go to a position on screen and press the left mouse button. When, 'y' is pressed, mouse pointer will go another position on screen and press the left mouse button. Here is my code:

```py
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller

mouse = Controller()

def on_press(key):
    if key == 'x':
        mouse.position = (1282, 255)
        mouse.press(Button.left)
    elif key == 'y':
        mouse.position = (1433, 434)
        mouse.press(Button.left)

def on_release(key):
    if key == 'x' or key == 'y':
        mouse.release(Button.left)
    elif key == Key.esc:
        return False

with Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Now, the problem is when both 'x' and 'y' are pressed at the same time. What I want is both the locations on screen should be clicked at the same time when both buttons are pressed together. But this is not happening since we have only one mouse pointer that both the events are trying to move.

But I believe this should be possible to do somehow since on a touchscreen laptop, one can tap on multiple positions of screen at the same time. So, instead of simulating mouse input, I want to simulate touch input in order to tap multiple parts of the screen at the same time. Is it possible to do using `pynput`? If not, is there another library that can do it?

Comment: Maybe you could use two threads.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA Can you guarantee they will execute the click in question at the same time?

Comment: @Cfomodz No, but why not have a try.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA It just seems like two threads are going to be, almost inherently, asynchronous.

Comment: @Arpan Biswas, is there a specific reason you're trying to do this? If it is for a specific reason, then maybe there is a simpler way to solve it. Or is it more like a "is this possible" type of question?

Comment: @5rod Implying they are, and I quote, "trying to do this" over 2 and a half years later is a bold choice, but I appreciate the comment nonetheless.